# Nginx return 404 after 60s execution

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm new with Nginx.
I have an ajax call to API endpoint. 
Sometimes executing this request taking a long time(more then 60s).
In this case nginx returning 404 error, but it is working fine with Apache.

This url exists and working fine if execution take less than 60s.

How to configure nginx not to return 404 when ajax call executing more than 60s?

Comment: `404` or `504`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806928/increasing-504-timeout-error/10850804

Comment: @ShawnC. Nope, exactly 404.